# C++ -'Stream' Undeclared identifier

Tags: windows, visual-studio, c++-cli

Newbie here  basically I want to load a file to the input stream. I get the following error

> error C2065: 'Stream' : undeclared identifier.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

namespace test2 {

  using namespace System;
  using namespace System::ComponentModel;
  using namespace System::Collections;
  using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
  using namespace System::Data;
  using namespace System::Drawing;


  public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
  {

    // ...

    private: System::Void browse_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        Stream^ myStream;
        OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;

        openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1->Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;

        if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
        {
            if ( (myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr )
            {
                //code
                myStream->Close();
            }
        }
    }

  };
}
```

Comment: You atre including only standard C++ headers but are referring to namespace System and using CLI pointer syntax - I bet there are some includes missing for the CLI classes you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) class is defined in the `System.IO` namespace, so you'll either need to…

- qualify the name of the type in the object declaration and all subsequent uses

  ```
  IO::Stream^ myStream;
  ```
- or add a `using` directive to the top of your code file

  ```
  using namespace System::IO;
  ```

Comment: That's qualified but not fully.

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to specify the correct namespace for the Stream class:

```
System::IO::Stream^ myStream;
```